# Is there an R package that speeds up lagging and differencing in time series analysis?

Tags: r, time-series

Currently, I need to define my own functions `lagpad()` and `diffpad()` (credits to Andrew and flexponsive) which automatically add an NA in the first rows:

```
lagpad <- function(x, k) {
  if (k>0) {
    return (c(rep(NA, k), x)[1 : length(x)] );
  }
  else {
    return (c(x[(-k+1) : length(x)], rep(NA, -k)));
  }
}

diffpad <- function(x,k){
  diff(zoo(x), na.pad=TRUE)
}
```

And if I wish to regress the change in a defined variable against a lagged defined variable, I need to create new variables in my dataset, as such:

```
muf$d.abc <- diffpad(muf$abc)
muf$l.xyz <- lagpad(muf$xyz, k=1)
```

Before I can finally regress them:

```
lm(d.abc ~ l.xyz, data=muf)
```

Are there any R packages that will help me skip the first two chunks of code altogether?

Comment: `lagpad` is the same as `dplyr::lag`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padding is unnecessary with zoo as there is no manual alignment needed in the first place.  For example, this regresses the first difference of `x` on its first two lags giving `fm2` and then on just one lag giving `fm1` and then performs an anova between them.  Note that anova here invokes `anova.dyn` which automatically reduces the arguments compared to the same response vector to make them comparable (otherwise you can't legitimately perform an anova).

```
library(dyn)

set.seed(123)
x0 <- rnorm(10)
x <- zoo(x0)

fm2 <- dyn$lm(diff(x) ~ lag(x, -(1:2)))
fm2 
##     Call:
##     lm(formula = dyn(diff(x) ~ lag(x, -(1:2))))
##    
##     Coefficients:
##         (Intercept)  lag(x, -(1:2))1  lag(x, -(1:2))2  
## 

fm1 <- dyn$lm(diff(x) ~ lag(x, -1))
anova(fm1, fm2)
## Analysis of Variance Table
## 
## Model 1: diff(x) ~ lag(x, -1)
## Model 2: diff(x) ~ lag(x, -(1:2))
##   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
## 1      6 7.4369                           
## 2      5 6.2441  1    1.1928 0.9551 0.3733
```

The dynlm package is an alternative to dyn.  It also facilitates performing regressions with zoo objects.

### Note

The above invokes the `lag` generic in the core of R and that in turn dispatches `lag.zoo`.  Be sure that you don't have dplyr's `lag` loaded as it overwrites R's `lag` with a version incompatible with R's `lag`.  Either don't load dplyr or i you need it then in sufficiently recent versions of R use `library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))`